# Laravel Vapor deployment issue - ssl certificate ownership

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-vapor

I am working with `Laravel 7.x` and `Vapor` (the latter for the first time). I have an issue where, on deployment of staging, I get the following error:

```
==> Ensuring IAM Role Exists
==> Ensuring Storage Exists
==> Ensuring Cache Table Is Configured
==> Ensuring Functions Exist
==> Updating Function Code
==> Updating Function Configurations
==> Updating Function Version
==> Ensuring Function Aliases Exist
==> Running Deployment Hooks
==> Ensuring Vanity Domain Certificate Exists
==> Ensuring Http API Is Configured

An error occurred during deployment.

Message: AWS: The certificate provided must be owned by the account creating the domain.
```

I am using the `Vapor` default network setup of `API Gwy 2` and have registered my domain and issued the certificate for `us-east-1` via the `Vapor` ui. I can see the certificate in `AWS`'s Certificate Manager console for that region.

I have deleted and recreated the certificate, both via the `Vapor` ui & cli and `AWS`, a number of times, but the error remains.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Login to the [Vapor Dashboard](https://vapor.laravel.com/app/domains/) and request a new certificate in the needed region. you can request more than one.

Comment: The moment you run into this problem ... and see your own awnser as accepted (... one year later).

Answer (score -1):

Solved this by deleteing all resources in Vapor, then deleting the rest of resources created by Vapor but left behind in AWS during the project delete.

Check and delete:

```
VPCs (check multiple regions in VPC Dashboard)
Subnets
Interfaces
Lambda fucntions
CDN
S3 buckets
```

Then remove `vapor.yml` and `vapor init` the project again.